# Subprocess stdout decode string wont work with greek letters

Tags: python, subprocess, decode, unicode-string, netsh

Im using the following subprocess call `c = subprocess.Popen("wmic nic where 'netconnectionid like '%οπικ%' and PhysicalAdapter=True' get netconnectionid",stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`. What i want to do is pass the netconnectionid (aka network adapter name) so i can pass it into a variable and use it here

`ip = self.ip_list.currentText()` 
`subprocess.Popen('netsh interface ipv4 set address name="' + sk + '" 
static 192.168.131.' + ip + ' 255.255.255.0 192.168.131.1')`

Im doing this because adapter names differ in different pcs. The problem is here :

`os = c.stdout.read()`

`sk = os.splitlines()[2].strip().decode('cp437')`

The result is 'Τοπική σύνδεση'.Im trying to convert the bytes to greek letters.I have tried utf-8 and it doesnt work. I tried printing the sk variable with .decode('cp437') and its the only decoding option that does right but after that,the netsh command wont work anyway.I tried renaming the adapter with english letters and decoding with utf-8 and it works so well.This is what i basically want to convert :

```
b'\xe7?\xe3??? \xe5??\xeb\xee\xe5?'
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: What do you mean 'it doesn't work'?

Comment: As if Pycharm retuns some random error code and nothing else. Idk why it does it but i noticed it happens when im using PyQt5

Comment: You'll need to add the error and traceback to your question.

Comment: "Process finished with exit code 1073741845" which i guess means its having trouble passing the variable to the netsh command since it's encoding is a mess since i cant find the right decoding option

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1032418/how-to-use-netsh-with-unicode-network-adapter-names Does this help?

Comment: Unfortunately not,i have read that post before. I want to pass the subprocess output to a variable but he takes a different approach

Answer (score 0):

Try using encoding **`utf-8`**.

```py
greek_string = 'Τοπική σύνδεση'
encoded_string = greek_string.encode('utf-8')
decoded_string = encoded_string.decode()
print('Original: {}\n\nEncoded: {}\nDecoded: {}'.format(greek_string, 
                                                        encoded_string, 
                                                        decoded_string))
```

**Output**:

```
Original: Τοπική σύνδεση

Encoded: b'\xce\xa4\xce\xbf\xcf\x80\xce\xb9\xce\xba\xce\xae \xcf\x83\xcf\x8d\xce\xbd\xce\xb4\xce\xb5\xcf\x83\xce\xb7'
Decoded: Τοπική σύνδεση
```

Comment: This is how i thought it works and it works that way. But apparently, it doesnt work that way when the output is from subprocess (using utf-8 decoding). Meaning when i try to print the result with utf-8 decoding, it prints nothing.